# woocommerce calculate and save price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, price

I have added custom fields to Woocommerce/Add Product/General tab using this excellent tutorial http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/

The custom fields (height, width, multiplier) are being saved to the database OK.
**I want to calculate a price based on the custom fields, and save the price to the database as the Regular Price**.
The problem is the price is not being saved.
Here is my code, from functions.php in my child theme:

```
/* CUSTOM FIELDS: Add custom fields to Product/General pane in Woocommerce
  from http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/ */

// Display Fields
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields');
// Save Fields
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save');

function woo_add_custom_general_fields()
{
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="options_group">';

    // Product Height
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_product_height',
            'label' => __('Product Height (inches)', 'woocommerce'),
            'placeholder' => '',
            'description' => __('Enter the product height in inches here.', 'woocommerce'),
            'type' => 'number',
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                'step' => 'any',
                'min' => '0'
            )
        )
    );

    // Product Width
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_product_width',
            'label' => __('Product Width (inches)', 'woocommerce'),
            'placeholder' => '',
            'description' => __('Enter the product width in inches here.', 'woocommerce'),
            'type' => 'number',
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                'step' => 'any',
                'min' => '0'
            )
        )
    );

    // Product Area Multiplier
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_product_area_mult',
            'label' => __('Product Area Multiplier', 'woocommerce'),
            'placeholder' => '',
            'description' => __('Enter Product Area Multiplier. ', 'woocommerce'),
            'type' => 'number',
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                'step' => 'any',
                'min' => '0'
            )
        )
    );

    // Product Area Price: added this field to check if this value is being calculated
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_product_area_price',
            'label' => __('Product Area Price', 'woocommerce'),
            'placeholder' => '',
            'description' => __('Product Area Price. Calculated automatically', 'woocommerce'),
            'type' => 'number',
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                'step' => 'any',
                'min' => '0'
            )
        )
    );

    echo '</div>';
}

function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save($post_id)
{
    $woocommerce_product_height = $_POST['_product_height'];
    $woocommerce_product_width = $_POST['_product_width'];
    $woocommerce_product_area_mult = $_POST['_product_area_mult'];
    $woocommerce_product_area_price = $_POST['_product_area_price'];

    // save height, width, multiplier
    if (!empty($woocommerce_product_height))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_height', esc_attr($woocommerce_product_height));

    if (!empty($woocommerce_product_width))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_width', esc_attr($woocommerce_product_width));

    if (!empty($woocommerce_product_area_mult))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_area_mult', esc_attr($woocommerce_product_area_mult));


    // calculate and save _product_area_price, _regular_price, price as Height*Width*Mult
    if (!empty($woocommerce_product_height) && !empty($woocommerce_product_width) && !empty($woocommerce_product_area_mult))
        $woocommerce_product_area_price = $woocommerce_product_height * $woocommerce_product_width * $woocommerce_product_area_mult;

    if (!empty($woocommerce_product_area_price))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_area_price', esc_attr($woocommerce_product_area_price));

    if (!empty($woocommerce_product_area_price))
    {
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_regular_price', esc_attr($woocommerce_product_area_price));
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_price', esc_attr($woocommerce_product_area_price));
    }
}
```

Everything is working except updating the price fields in the database. My custom fields are updated with the same syntax. I confirmed that the variable `$woocommerce_product_area_price` exists, and it is updating custom field, but the same variable is not updating `_regular_price` or `_price` fields. So these lines are not working, even though the same variable will update the `_product_area_price` field:

```
if (!empty($woocommerce_product_area_price))
{
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_regular_price', esc_attr($woocommerce_product_area_price));
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_price', esc_attr($woocommerce_product_area_price));
}
```

Maybe there's some syntax or check I am missing for updating the price in Woocommerce?

Comment: Have you checked in the DB that price is getting save or not? or you problem is that it is not getting reflected in frontend?

Comment: Not getting saved to database, Raunak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I thing that you have an issue with Price that is showing in frontend. You need to update `_price` key if you want to reflect `_regular_price` in frontend.

Try this code:

```
if (!empty($area_price)){
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_regular_price', esc_attr($area_price));
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_price', esc_attr($area_price)); //<-- Add this line.
}
```

**UPDATED**

Just add a **higher priority** to `woocommerce_process_product_meta` action hook, it 'll do the trick.

```
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save', 99);
```

I have tested it and it is working fine.
Hope this helps!

Comment: @user3547460: can you please update your question as what hook you have used for `woo_add_custom_general_fields_save`.

Comment: I included complete code snippet to show that the hook is woocommerce_process_product_meta